# Confusion in processing of Schengen visa for Italy

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I applied for Schengen visa on 28'August at VFS Hyderabad, India. Till 31'August, the status was shown as your visa application has been dispatched to Consulate of Italy, Mumbai for processing.

On 01'September, the status is reflecting as the processed visa application has been dispatched from the embassy of Italy, New Delhi to Hyderabad AC.

Hyderabad falls under the jurisdiction of Mumbai centre for visa processing, then how come my application has reached New Delhi. In fact, the initial status was shown as the application dispatched to Mumbai for processing.

I am confused.

Has anyone here on the board has such experience in past?

Comment: Don't read too much into those messages. They are automated status updates and sometimes don't make much sense. Wait for the one that tells you to collect your passport.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whatever messages you get when you [track your application](https://www.vfsvisaonline.com/Global-Passporttracking/Track/), applications are assessed and decided by a country's visa section, in this case that of Italy.

As embassies/consulates process visa applications, which are tracked electronically, it triggers generic status updates. There's no need to fret, even if the information seems confusing; simply await the key message that a decision has been reached.